# How an op-amp determines its output without a reference point?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, voltage-reference, inverting-amplifier, reference

I was struggling to understand how an op-amp determines its output without a reference point.

The output of an op-amp is A * (Vni - Vi)

Then let's say we have an inverting op-amp with a gain of 1000, that V+ is 9 V, V- is -9 V and Vni is 5 V.

If Vi is 5.002 V, the output is 1000 * (5 - 5.002)  =  -2 V

If Vi is 4.998 V, the output is 1000 * (5 - 4.998)  =  2 V

The output is -2 V or 2 V but with respect to where? With respect to the halfway between 9 V and -9 V or Vni (5 V)?

So how can I set the reference point of the op-amp?

Thanks in advance.

Note: Vi is the inverting input and Vni is the non-inverting input of the op-amp.

Edit: Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: Please use a full stop '.' as a decimal point, not a comma ',' as that's the norm for this site. I thought you were up in the kV on the first read. Edited.

Comment: In Europe you used comma as a decimal point

Comment: As for the question, Try to watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbMnQdRzD8A

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can assume midway between the supplies.

It actually doesn't matter much for most high-gain op-amps since you can translate the input offset voltage into a change in output offset voltage by multiplying by the gain, and that number is usually many times the power supply voltage(s).

For example, take an LM324 which has a gain of 100,000 typically and an offset voltage of +/-2mV typically. That translates to +/-200V at the output, so the particular reference point you pick on a +/-9V supply only makes a difference of less than +/-90uV at the input.

Real op-amps also have finite CMRR and usually we assume the inputs are **also** at or near the midpoint of the supplies. Away from that you'll effectively have a change in input offset voltage (sometimes quite significant). To be sure, check out the datasheet conditions for measurement of CMRR and Vos.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the good question. It's often asked at the beginning of learning opamps. You should noticed that you used your opamp without the feedback loop. Thus, you have a comparator. But still you will have the output voltage. Usually it is the halfway between the positive and negative rails. So just for learning you can assume 0 V in your case as you have +9 V and -9 V. Hence you will have -2 V and +2 V at the output.

Keep in mind that, the opamp is not a black box. It has elements inside. Simple class A opamp in two situations:

1. when inputs are equal to 0.9 V:

[image: opamp 0.9V input]

2. when inputs are equal to 3.2 V:

[image: opamp 3.2V input]

Ideally, when the inputs are equal to each other the output should be 1.65V (half of the power supply). In reality it depends on CMRR, matching, corners etc. Hence, you should use the feedback, e.g.:

[image: opamp inverting configuration]

Here, you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the reference?
>   Here V(+) and V(-) have no effect on Vout as long as they are sufficient and in spec.

Can you see where the 0V reference on the output comes from?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3vNAd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An Op Amp always needs negative feedback , but the reference to 0V output must always come from one of the inputs, even though there may be no direct 0V input, such as a resistor or voltage supply that comes from 0V.

I trust you can figure out the details.

It is always important to check the datasheet for CM Input range and Output swing with any supply voltage to ensure of linear operation.

Comment: the 2nd schematic should read 0.5V at both opamp inputs.

Comment: Yes of course ty